# How do I change the server of a player Bungeecord

Tags: java, minecraft, bukkit, bungeecord

I was wondering how I can move the target server of the player I dont have any code so far and I have found nothing but I am making a plugin for private use for my Minecraft server network. I do already have a plugin called [Command Sync](https://www.spigotmc.org/resources/commandsync.115/) which links my BungeeCord Server and my Spigot Servers with `sync console bungee send @p tntwars` in vanilla where `tntwars` is my target server.
This is all I know because the Spigot forums are terrible and useless>

How do I move that player to another server?

Comment: I think you could use tjis lines:String[] cmd = {"/bin/sh", "-c", "stty raw </dev/tty"};
Runtime.getRuntime().exec(cmd);

Comment: This question makes absolutely no sense. Please take a minute to read it again. Pretend you know absolutely nothing beforehand (as we do) and ask yourself if it would make sense to you. We know nothing except what you've explained in your post, and the information you've provided isn't useful. See [ask].

Comment: @KenWhite The thing is is that I am making it the best that I can when there isn't a site for what I am what to ask but this is the closest to what I want. I have made a proposal for it as Games and Programming

Comment: So, just to clear things up: You want to move a player to another server in your BungeeCord network. Do you want to do that via console, via an ingame command or somehow else?

Comment: @KenWhite This question is straight forward given the tag of bungeecord.

Comment: @RyanTheLeach Thank you

Answer (score 5, accepted):

**From Bungee Plugins:**

See https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/sending-players-between-servers-in-bungeecord/

```
ServerInfo target = ProxyServer.getInstance().getServerInfo("Hub");
player.connect(target);
```

**From Spigot Plugins:**

See https://www.spigotmc.org/wiki/bukkit-bungee-plugin-messaging-channel/#connect

Connect Example to server.
(Used when `Example` is a player connected to the server sending the command, e.g. 'kick' to server)

```
 ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
 out.writeUTF("Connect");
 out.writeUTF("pvp");    
 //applies to the player you send it to. aka Kick To Server.
 Player player = Bukkit.getPlayerExact("Example");
 player.sendPluginMessage(this, "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());
```

ConnectOther Example to server. (Used when you need to pull a player out of another server on the network, care should be used to make sure they arn't mid-minigame or something, as you won't necessarily have the server-state context of the player)

```
 ByteArrayDataOutput out = ByteStreams.newDataOutput();
 out.writeUTF("ConnectOther");
 out.writeUTF("Example");
 out.writeUTF("pvp");
 //Any online player at all.
 //Aka Pull To Server.
 Player player = Iterables.getFirst(Bukkit.getOnlinePlayers(), null);
 player.sendPluginMessage(this, "BungeeCord", out.toByteArray());
```

You can not send a message to Bungee without any online players!

Comment: Can i use this code on my Spigot server but for my bungee cord server

Comment: I've edited to provide an example for spigot servers.